# How to trigger script node update from Blender python?

Tags: python, blender

I have a Blender model, that uses a script to generate a shader. This script takes as input the output of a Value Node, and uses this value to generate a pattern.

I would like to use a python Blender script to:
- change the "Value" being fed into the script
- perform the "script node update" as if I was pressing the button in the script node
- render and save.

I'd be looping through a set of 20 "values" so want to do this in one click.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way to do what I wanted was to actually update the default value for the input parameters to the script node. This actually triggers the script to update at the same time.

nodeScript.inputs[2].default_value = 100